# overhead of changing sensor sampling time

Tags: embedded, iot, sensors, sampling, robotics

I am looking for the potential overhead of changing the sampling time (not sampling rate) of sensors in embedded systems/robotics/IoT. For example, let's say the sensor is a camera connected to a raspberry pi capturing pictures every 100 ms at 0,100ms,200ms,300ms,...  What will happen if I change the sampling time to 50ms,150ms,250ms,...? Do I have to initialize the sensor again? or does it reduce the performance of applications that are using the sensor? Any example is appreciated. You can consider any other type of sensor as well if you have a sensor/system in mind. again, I am looking for the potential overhead of changing the sampling time.

Comment: Just like "IoT", "sensor" is a very broad and unhelpful term in real-world electronics. A "sensor" could be anything from a simple thermistor to a hall effect sensor to some complex MEMS IC. You'll need to be far more specific - the question doesn't make any sense. What is measured, what is the output unit you get, how long does it take to make a measurement, how often do you need to sample and so on.

Comment: edited the post. hopefully, it is more clear now. I am designing a method that requires changing the sensor sampling time(right now a camera and raspberry pi, but it can be any other sensor as well). I am looking for a situation that changing sampling time is undesirable.

Comment: It doesn't make sense still. How fast is the camera, how often do you need to take photos? You need a real-time specification to make sense of it. For example if you mean to capture motions there needs to be some manner of resolution specification. Also notable Rasp Pi is a hobbyist computer running Linux and not a real-time system, so you already threw real-time requirements out the window.

Comment: my target application is periodic long applications(for example, the app runs at 10htz for a day). I am more looking for these types of examples: example1: sensor x takes 1 second to change its sampling time. example2: in system y, the application z gets the sensor data at certain times (probably because it is a RTOS), and if the sensor sampling time changes, the sensor data needs to wait till be application z runs again. in both example1 and example2, changing sampling time is not recommended, unless it is really necessary.